# How to work with Windows SMB connections in QGIS on Linux/Debian?

Tags: qgis, linux-mint

I'm having trouble accessing our Windows shared drives in QGIS while working on Linux Mint.

For some reason I don't remember this being a problem prior to version 3.4, but here is the issue:

Our shared team drive sits on a Windows server, which we access via a mapped drive in Windows. This works well in QGIS on Windows, as the standard 'browse' dialogue boxes show mapped drives, etc.

However, the browse dialogues in QGIS on Linux - now using Mint v19 - don't show any detail:

[image]

Can anyone think of a way to access drives that have been added via SMB and available at the desktop level, but not accessible to QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mount your SMB shares via the file manager (which is Nemo in Mint, Nautilus for Ubuntu/Debian), in the background they are mounted with `gvfs` (old, deprecated) or `gio` (new).

For programs that do not show these locations, you can find the mount point in `/run/user/$UID/gvfs` or `/run/user/$UID/gio`.

`$UID` is usually 1000 for a single user system.

See [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33480/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-samba-location-ive-mounted-in-nautilus-on-the-command-li) on askubuntu with more details.

Comment: that works! I wonder if its worth putting in a feature request to have this interface improved? Thanks!!!

Comment: The file dialog is not QGIS specific, it's from GTK3 which already has a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1714518) filed for that. Should be fixed in future versions.

Comment: Thanks - seeing that in other applications like PyCharm... I've been coming back to this thread for the answer, so thanks again!

Comment: it seems this bug may have been fixed? Do you know when this might be added to QGIS?